# Stuck on infinitely looping NextAuth authentication

Tags: next.js, next-auth, okta

I'm totally stuck on next auth infinitely looping on my next project. We recently made the main page of the app the defacto "home" page so I updated that page's name to `index.tsx` making it root. ever since then its like it gets trapped in this redirect hell. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

its worth noting our app doesn't have a sign on page perse but rather you're redirected to Okta's SSO flow. All recomendations I found for handling this use case said to create a `signin.tsx` which basically just tests session status then either calls the sign in function for Okta or redirects you to '/'. then in pages/index I've had a redirect also directing you to 'auth/signin' which docs have said to do in order to protect certain routes. but even without that bit of code in the getServerSideProps it STILL infinitely loops. I feel like its too much complexity? can someone who has a clue help me thin some of this out? what don't I need?

**[...NEXTAUTH]**

```
export const authOptionsFunction = (): AuthOptions => {
    return {
        providers: [
            Okta({
                //@ts-ignore
                clientId: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID as string,
                //@ts-ignore
                clientSecret: Config.OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
                //@ts-ignore
                issuer: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_ISSUER as string,
                // clientId: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID as string,
                // clientSecret: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
                // issuer: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_ISSUER as string,
            })
        ],
        //@ts-ignore
        secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
        //secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
        session: { strategy: 'jwt'},
        callbacks: {
            async jwt({ token, account }: any) {
                if (account) {
                    token.accessToken = account.access_token;
                    token.idToken = account.id_token;
                    token.oktaId = account.providerAccountId
                }
                var tokenParsed = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.accessToken.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString());
                const dateNowInSeconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000
                if (dateNowInSeconds > tokenParsed.exp) {
                    throw Error("expired Okta access token");
                }
                return token;
            },
            async session({ session, token }: any) {
                // get our native current user data here 
                const res = await GET_CURRENT_USER(token);
                const { data } = await res.json();

                session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
                session.idToken = token.idToken;
                session.oktaId = token.oktaId;
                session.currentUser =  data;
    
                return session;
            },
            async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials}) {
                return true;
            },
            async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
                // Allows relative callback URLs
                if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`
                // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
                else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url
                return baseUrl
            }
        },
        debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        pages: {
            signIn: "/auth/signin",
        },

    }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = authOptionsFunction()

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

**MIDDLEWARE**

```
export default withAuth(
    (req: NextRequest & { nextauth: { token: JWT | null } }) => {

        if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/auth') || req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')) {
            return NextResponse.next();
        }
        // if there is no session
        if (!req.nextauth.token) {
            req.nextUrl.pathname = '/auth/signin';
            return NextResponse.redirect(req.nextUrl);
        }
        return NextResponse.next();
    },
    {
        callbacks: {
            authorized() {
                return true
            },
        },
        pages: {
            signIn: "/auth/signin",
        },

    }
);
```

**SIGN IN COMPONENT**

```
const SignIn = () => {

    const { status } = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
            signIn('okta');
        } else if (status === 'authenticated') {
            router.push('/');
        }
    }, [status]);

    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}

export default SignIn;
```

**PAGES / INDEX **

this little bit is just a part of getServerSideProps - the rest of the page is just a standard Page, ya know? fetch the props, pass the props, use the props.

```
     if (!session) {
         return {
             redirect: {
                 destination: '/auth/signin',
                 permanent: false,
             }
         }
     }
```